# Pages orientation depending on condition

Tags: xsl-fo

im trying to change my document page orientation depending on conditions, but I dont know how this can be done. Reading the documentation didn't help much and couldn't find any examples.

I set my document like this:

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="first-page" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21.0cm" margin="1cm 2.1cm 0.8cm 2.1cm">
          <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body" margin-top="105px" margin-bottom="50px"/>
          <fo:region-before region-name="xsl-region-before-first" extent="5in"/>
          <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after" extent="5in" display-align="after"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="other-page" page-height="21.0cm" page-width="29.7cm" margin="1cm 2.1cm 0.8cm 2.1cm">
      <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body" margin-top="105px" margin-bottom="50px"/>
      <fo:region-before region-name="xsl-region-before-other" extent="5in"/>
      <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after" extent="5in" display-align="after"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
        <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="pages">
      <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
              <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="first" master-reference="first-page"/>
              <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="only" master-reference="other-page"/>
      </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
        </fo:page-sequence-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>


<fo:page-sequence master-reference="pages">
 <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before-first">
...
 </fo:static-content>
 <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before-first">
...
 </fo:static-content>
 <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before-first">
...
 </fo:static-content>
 <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
 ...
 </fo:flow>
```

This is generating a first vertical page first, and then all the rest are horizontal pages. These horizontal pages are being generated in a for-each loop. What I would like to do is that after a specific page-before="break" which could be in any position, I could change the layout of the following page depending on the data of the for-each items.

Edit: Im using xmlns:fo version 2.0 My exact document should look like this:

- First page (working fine)
- X pages: LANDSCAPE VIEW, generated using a for-each loop overe itemsA (working fine)
- Y pages: PORTRAIT VIEW, generated using a for-each loop overe itemsB (this is what i dont know how to do, how to change from landscape to portrait)

```
    <xsl:for-each select="itemsA">
    ...printed stuff...
    </xsl:for-each>
    <fo:block break-before="page">
    <xsl:for-each select="itemsB">
    ...printed stuff...
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: What XSLT version are you using? Can you show an example of your XML and the relevant portion of your XSLT?  The answer is likely to be that you should generate a new `fo:page-sequence` when you want to change the layout (unless you are using nested page sequences with AH Formatter), but how to group your elements into `fo:page-sequence` will be easier with XSLT 2.0 or XSLT 3.0 than it would be with XSLT 1.0.

Comment: I updated my question, hope it is clearer now

Comment: You might be using XSLT 2.0, but you can't be using XSL-FO 2.0 since that doesn't exist. The latest version of XSL-FO is defined in XSL 1.1: https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make a separate `fo:page-sequence-master` (or `fo:simple-page-master` if there's no variation between left/right pages, etc.).
2. Move your `fo:page-sequence-master` to within each `xsl:for-each`, with the `fo:page-sequence-master` referring to the appropriate `fo:page-sequence-master` (or `fo:simple-page-master).

I.e.:

```
<xsl:for-each select="itemsA">
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="landscape">
    ...printed stuff...
  </fo:page-sequence>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="itemsB">
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="portrait">
    ...printed stuff...
  </fo:page-sequence>
</xsl:for-each>
```

You would not need the `<fo:block break-before="page">` because the `fo:page-sequence` always generates a new page sequence.